# Importing opencv brew install on OSX Lion causes segfault

Tags: python, opencv

I have already installed numpy and scipy via pip (both import properly) and have the latest XCode with command line tools.  Opencv used to work at one point but is now causing a segfault when I attempt to import it in python.  I'm using python 2.7.3 installed through brew.

I attempted gdb python with run -c "import cv2" and only received:

```
#0  0x00007fff5fc01028 in __dyld__dyld_start ()
#1  0x0000000100000000 in ?? ()
```

In response to the backtrace.  My PYTHONPATH is set to "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH".  I've tried reinstalling using the build-from-source options along with --use-clang, --use-llvm, and --use-gcc just to see if it's a weird compiler issue.  I also attempted to export GCC=gcc-4.2 and GXX=g++-4.2 before compiling.

Any ideas on troubleshooting this install?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a compiler issue.  As I wanted to use brew installs by default, I had /usr/local/bin first in my path.  Opencv was compiling with brew's gcc version 4.7.  It also looks as though after exporting GCC=gcc-4.2 and GXX=g++-4.2, homebrew wasn't referencing these environment variables to find out which compiler it should use.

Comment: This should be a comment.